# Vue: Create a parent component that can render a child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How can I create a parent component that can receive and render a child component?

For example:

```
<Form> 
   <Input/>
   <Input/>
   <Select/>
   <Button/>
<Form/>
```

Comment: So `Form` is the parent component?
`Input`, `Select`, `Button` are children?

Answer (score 2):

### You can use [slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html).

Parent.vue

```
<template>
 <form>

  <slot/> <!-- The child component will be rendered here -->

 </form>
</template>
```

Child.vue

```
<template>
 <div>

  <input/>
  <input/>

 </div>
</template>
```

Grandparent.vue

```
<template>
 <div>

  <Parent> <!-- Parent component -->
   <Child/> <!-- Pass child component to it as slot -->
  </Parent>

 </div>
</template>

<script>
import Parent from './Parent.vue'
import Child from './Child.vue'

components: {
 Parent,
 Child
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should import the components as follows:

```
import Select from "../components/Select";
import Button from "../components/Button";
import Input from "../components/Input";
```

And then register them in the parent as follows:

```
components: {
    Select,
    Button,
    Input
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send your child components to another component, say parent component, using `slots`.

You need to assign a name to the child components like

```
<Form> 
   <Input name="input1"/>
   <Input name="input2"/>
   <Select name="select"/>
   <Button name="button"/>
<Form/>
```

Then inside the parent component, you can receive it like

```
<template>
 <form>
  <slot name="input1"/>
  <slot name="input2"/>
  <slot name="select"/>
  <slot name="button"/>
 </form>
</template>
```

The slots with corresponding names will be replaced with the child components.